# React-native does not support IPFS?

Tags: react-native

I installed IPFS in my app and whenever I am trying to use it I always get this error.

```
Error: undefined Unable to resolve module `crypto` from `node_modules/libp2p-crypto/src/hmac/index.js`
```

I searched on google and found article which says it is impossible to use IPFS on mobile device.
But this article was created almost 1 year ago and I was wondering is it still true for react-native?
Is there any ways to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

To query an IPFS node I use [ipfs-mini](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-mini)

Works great for my react-native app.